# Can't Modify Dataframe with Multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, dataframe, multiprocessing

I'm struggling to modify my dataframe while doing Multiprocessing.
Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
data_attrib.loc[:, 'Id'] = ['' for _ in range(len(data_attrib))]

def myfunction(i):
     data_attrib.at[i, 'Id'] = i
     print(data_attrib.at[i, 'Id'])

import multiprocessing
processes = []
for i in data_attrib.index:
    #launch multiprocessing
    pro = multiprocessing.Process(target = myfunction, args = [i])
    pro.start()
    processes.append(pro)
for process in processes:
    process.join()
```

Without Multiprocessing the function works perfectly. However, with multiprocessing it correctly  executes the function but the column data_attrib["Id"] remains empty.

Could anyone tell me why and how to fix it.
Thanks!

Comment: This code couldn't possibly execute without getting into a recursive loop and throwing an exception. Perhaps it's too oversimplified.

Comment: @Booboo I definitely oversimplified it a lot for the sake of the question. However, just out of curiosity, I actually executed the above script on my Spyder environment and it executed without problem.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Spyder environment, but if you look at the first example in my answer (or any of the examples) and remove the `if` test surrounding the call to `main()`, it will definitely throw an exception when the program is called from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems. First, when you do multiprocessing the code that launches the processes must be within a block that is governed by an `if __name__ == '__main__':` test. Otherwise when the sub-process is launched the process-launching code will be re-executed and you will have sub-processes launching further sub-processes in an infinite recursion loop.

Second, unlike with threading, each process runs in its own memory space, so any global variables that it modifies will not be reflected in other processes. For example, here is an attempt to correct both of your problems (albeit just using a simple list rather than a dataframe to demonstrate) by passing the list as an argument:

```
import multiprocessing


def myfunction(l, i):
    l[i] += 1


def main():
    l = [i for i in range(3)]
    processes = []
    for i in range(3):
        #launch multiprocessing
        pro = multiprocessing.Process(target = myfunction, args = (l, i))
        pro.start()
        processes.append(pro)
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
    print(l)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

The original list was not modified because what was passed to the sub-processes were copies of the list. The program would have to be modified instead to have the subprocess return the modified value and for the main process itself to do the actual updating of the list. But getting return values from using `Process` is not that straightforward. For getting return values it is better to use either the `Pool` class from the `multiprocessing.pool` module or the `ProcessPoolExecutor` class from the `concurrent.futures` module.

But there is another way of accomplishing what you need to do without passing return values back by by allowing multiple processes to operate on a single copy of an object through proxies. This is provided by the `Manager` class from the `multiprocessing` module.

```
import multiprocessing


def myfunction(l, i):
    l[i] += 1


def main():
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
        l = manager.list()
        for i in range(3):
            l.append(i)
        processes = []
        for i in range(3):
            #launch multiprocessing
            pro = multiprocessing.Process(target = myfunction, args = (l, i))
            pro.start()
            processes.append(pro)
        for process in processes:
            process.join()
        print(l)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

You will clearly need to read up on the `Manager` class and see how it might be adapted for your specific problem. The `Manager` class gives you choices, but not an infinite number. If you want to continue using a Dataframe, you may have to get creative.

The following code does not use the `Manager` class and each sub-process is working on its own copy of the input data. Instead, each process returns its modified value(s) back to the main process who reassembles the final result:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

l = [i for i in range(3)]

def myfunction(i):
    return l[i] + 1


def main():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        results = executor.map(myfunction, range(3))
        for i, result in enumerate(results):
            l[i] = result
        print(l)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I used the Manager class and proxies as you suggested: worked perfectly!
I assigned all the values I needed to the ListProxy and, once finished, I added  the list to my Dataframe. Looks like it's working alright for now. 
Thanks again!

Comment: I am glad, but you should then "Accept" the answer. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63170842/cant-modify-dataframe-with-multiprocessing?noredirect=1#comment111717060_63170842).